# How to adjust the font of tick labels for a percent-formatted axis in matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib, fonts

I usually use `matplotlib` with the following options:

```py
matplotlib.rcParams['text.latex.preamble'] = r'\usepackage{amsmath}'
matplotlib.rc('text', usetex = True)
```

such that the text font looks better (at least to me).
However, if I format one of the axis to percent,
the font of tick labels on that axis will fall back to the default.
Here is an MWE:

```py
import numpy as np

import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('Agg')
matplotlib.rcParams['text.latex.preamble'] = r'\usepackage{amsmath}'
matplotlib.rc('text', usetex = True)
from matplotlib import pyplot as py

## setup figure
figure = py.figure(figsize = (7.5, 5.0))
axs = [py.subplot(1, 1, 1)]

## make plot
xs = np.linspace(0.0, np.pi, 100)
ys = np.sin(xs)
axs[0].plot(xs, ys, color = 'dodgerblue', label = r'$n = 1$')
ys = np.sin(2.0 * xs)
axs[0].plot(xs, ys, color = 'seagreen', label = r'$n = 2$')
axs[0].axhline(0.0, color = 'gray', linestyle = 'dashed')

## percentage y axis
formatter = matplotlib.ticker.PercentFormatter(xmax = 1.0, decimals = 0, symbol = r'\%', is_latex = True)
axs[0].yaxis.set_major_formatter(formatter)

## save figure
name = 'test.pdf'
py.tight_layout()
py.savefig(name)
py.close()
```

As shown below, the font on vertical axis is different from that of the horizontal,
how do I set it to be the same as that of the horizontal axis?
Thanks!

[image: percent-formatted-axis]

Answer (score 0):

I found a workaround, it is not perfect, but it solves the problem:

```py
import numpy as np

import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('Agg')
matplotlib.rcParams['text.latex.preamble'] = r'\usepackage{amsmath}'
matplotlib.rc('text', usetex = True)
from matplotlib import pyplot as py

## setup figure
figure = py.figure(figsize = (7.5, 5.0))
axs = [py.subplot(1, 1, 1)]

## make plot
xs = np.linspace(0.0, np.pi, 100)
ys = np.sin(xs)
axs[0].plot(xs, ys, color = 'dodgerblue', label = r'$n = 1$')
ys = np.sin(2.0 * xs)
axs[0].plot(xs, ys, color = 'seagreen', label = r'$n = 2$')
axs[0].axhline(0.0, color = 'gray', linestyle = 'dashed')

## percentage y axis
y_low, y_up = axs[0].get_ylim()
y_ticks = [_ for _ in axs[0].get_yticks() if (_ > y_low) and (_ < y_up)]
y_labels = [r'${:g}\%$'.format(_ * 100.0) for _ in y_ticks]
axs[0].set_yticks(y_ticks)
axs[0].set_yticklabels(y_labels)
## ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ see this part ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^

## save figure
name = 'test.pdf'
py.tight_layout()
py.savefig(name)
py.close()
```

So instead of using `matplotlib.ticker.PercentFormatter`, I now define the tick labels manually.
This produces:

[image: percentage y axis]